# Why does Cross-sex hormone therapy have an opposite effect on cortical thickness?

Tags: developmental-psychology, neuroimaging, gender, sex-differences

In a recent lecture I was informed that cross-sex hormone therapy increases the cortical thickness in FtMs, but decreases CTh in MtFs. Why does this happen when studies find females have increased cortical thickness compared to males? Additionally, why does the hormone therapy have this effect at all?

sources: [cross sex hormone paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/24617977)  Female cortical thickness differences papers:
[1](https://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2329809)
[2](https://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6871390)